# Changing color on frontend sets price to zero

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, javascript, ce-1.9.1.0

I have a configurable product with a few simple products assigned to it. On the frontend I see the price of the product correctly. In the dropdown box with different colors (underlying simple products) I see

> Black
>
> Chrome +€5.00

This is exactly what is should be. However when I select one of the colors, the price of the product is changed to €0,00. But when I add the product to cart, the correct price is displayed. It looks like only the calculation (in javascript?) of the price on the product is wrong.

I use Magento 1.9.1.0 with a bought template. I have no idea how to solve this. See here the link where this problem occurs:
http://www.eenwieler.nl/eenwielers/standaard-eenwielers/20-inch/only-one-20-inch-eenwieler.html

Comment: I see the theme did not change the core JS files. Did you try to reindex the products & prices? And also a clear cache after the reindex.

Comment: Just tried this. Unfortunately this doesn't help...

Comment: Does it work correctly if you choose the base theme?